# Lagrange's Theorem for further elementary consequences

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question: Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $H$ and $K$ be subgroup of $G$. Prove: suppose $H$ and $G$ are not equal, and both have order the same prime number $p$, Then $H\cap K=\{e\}$.

This is my proof steps:

Proof: $G$ is finite, $H, K$ subgroup of $G$. therefore $H\cap K$ subgroup of $G$, also is subgroup of both $H$ and $K$
Then the order of $H\cap K$ is a common divisor of order of $H$ and the order of $K$. since $p$ is prime number. Show that $G$ is cyclic group and that any a belong to $G$ is its generator.  Therefore $H,K, H\cap K$ are cyclic group too, because every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Since $H$ not equal $G$, Then …..
I just did here, because I feel I miss some part. Can anyone give me some advises! Thanks so much

Comment: It is not true in general, that $G$ is a cylcic group. But you already did all the work: $ord(H\cap K)$ devides $ord(K) = ord(H) = p$ prime. Just answer the following questions to yourself: Can $ord(H \cap K)$ be equal to $p$? What can it equal?

Comment: no! order(H∩K) can not equal p, it should be {e}

Comment: From where is this "*Show that $G$ is cyclic group*" coming in the middle of the proof of something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assume $G$ is cyclic, nor can you prove it, becasue not all finite groups are cyclic.

Your proof is very good up to where you say the order of $H \cap K$ is a common divisor of the orders of both the groups $H$ and $K$.  At this point, note that the only divisors of a prime $p$ are 1 and $p$ itself.  What does this mean about $H \cap K$?  How many elements can it have?

Comment: when their order prime p equal 1 therefore H∩K ={e}, otherwise when their order prime p not equal 1, since H and K not equal each other , H∩K ={e}?

Comment: @megan When $H \cap K$ has order 1, you are correct that $H \cap K$ must be the identity (it can only have one element).  When $H \cap K$ has order $p$, then it has $p$ elements, and also it is a subgroup of $H$ and $K$, and both $H$ and $K$ have $p$ elements. What does this mean?

Comment: H equal K, therefore it is contradiction, because H not equal K